# Дата в php

Tags: дата, php

Здравствуйте.

Есть конструкция, которая выводит даты от одного числа (за 10 дней до сегодня) и на месяц:

```
$date_from=date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))-86400*9);
$date_next=$date_from;
do {

      ?>

        <tr>
            <th><?=$date_next?></th>
        </tr>

        <?php

        $date_next=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date_next)+86400);

    } while ($date_next<date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date_from)+86400*31));
```

Все работает хорошо, но когда вместо 31 дня пытаюсь вывести 2 года, начинается бесконечный цикл на дате 2014-10-25.
С чем может быть связано, может, знаете? Спасибо.

Comment: > начинается бесконечный цикл на дате 2014-10-25

Как вы это определили?

Comment: Запустил этот скрипт, и, дойдя до этой даты, начинает повторять ее.

Answer (score 1):

Переход на зимнее время:  +86400 даёт всё ещё ту же дату. 26-го октября в 2 часа стрелки часов переводятся на час назад. Т.о. прибавление 86400 секунд даёт всё ещё ту же дату.

Стоит отказаться от порочной практики прибавления секунд, а использовать [`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php) и добавлять именно 1 день.

Answer (score 0):

Мой совет: при работе с датами используйте лучше TimeStamp, т.е. дата/время в секундах, с числовыми переменными меньше заморочек будет при сравнении двух дат.

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробовал запустить ваш код, у меня все работает: http://ideone.com/7ehrvl
2. Откуда у вас появилась дата 2014-10-25? вчера было 18.11.2014, по алгоритму -9 дней это 09.11.2014 и считаем на "+2 года" от старта. Вы меняли настройки даты сервера?